# how to merge list of tuples and a list of unequal length?

Tags: python, list, merge, tuples

```
list_1 = ['amt_doc_post','grn_std_qty_kg','po_gross_value','po_num_count','po_qty']
list_2 = [('lag_3', 'lag_3', 'lag_3', 'lag_3', 'lag_3'),
 ('lag_3', 'lag_3', 'lag_3', 'lag_3', 'lag_4'),
 ('lag_3', 'lag_3', 'lag_3', 'lag_4', 'lag_3'),
     ('lag_4', 'lag_4', 'lag_4', 'lag_4', 'lag_4'),...]
```

> i have created second list using product command from itertools

```
lag_range = ['lag_3', 'lag_4', 'lag_5', 'lag_6', 'lag_7', 'lag_8', 'lag_9']

list_2 = list(itertools.product(lag_range[2:4], repeat=5))
```

> i tried this earlier but it doesnt provide repetition of lag variable

```
all_combo = [list(zip(x,lag_list)) for x in itertools.permutations(lag_range,len(lag_list))]
print(all_combo[1:3] # a sample list of tuples view

[[('lag_1', 'amt_doc_post'), ('lag_2', 'grn_std_qty_kg'), ('lag_3', 'po_gross_value'), ('lag_4', 'po_num_count'), ('lag_6', 'po_qty')], [('lag_1', 'amt_doc_post'), ('lag_2', 'grn_std_qty_kg'), ('lag_3', 'po_gross_value'), ('lag_4', 'po_num_count'), ('lag_7', 'po_qty')]]
```

> i want output as a combination of both the list & list of tuples:

```
[[('amt_doc_post','lag_3'), ('grn_std_qty_kg','lag_3'),('po_gross_value','lag_3'), ('po_num_count','lag_3'),('po_qty','lag_3')], [('amt_doc_post','lag_3'), ('grn_std_qty_kg','lag_3'),('po_gross_value','lag_3'), ('po_num_count','lag_3'),('po_qty','lag_4')],...]
```

> i know, i must be missing something silly, please help me out here

Comment: Can you post a smaller example? it's a bit hard to follow

Comment: @funnydman, please ignore lengthy list_2 elements, you can consider even 2 lines from list_2, problem would remain same

Answer (score 2):

In order to obtain something like this

```
[[('amt_doc_post', 'lag_3'),
  ('grn_std_qty_kg', 'lag_3'),
  ('po_gross_value', 'lag_3'),
  ('po_num_count', 'lag_3'),
  ('po_qty', 'lag_3')],
[('amt_doc_post', 'lag_3'),
 ('grn_std_qty_kg', 'lag_3'),
 ('po_gross_value', 'lag_3'),
 ('po_num_count', 'lag_3'),
 ('po_qty', 'lag_4')]]
```

you can do like this:

```
list_1 = ['amt_doc_post','grn_std_qty_kg','po_gross_value','po_num_count','po_qty']
list_2 = [('lag_3', 'lag_3', 'lag_3', 'lag_3', 'lag_3'),
          ('lag_3', 'lag_3', 'lag_3', 'lag_3', 'lag_4')]

result = [list(zip(list_1, x)) for x in list_2]
```